# How to Create Dynamic (Custom Fields Supported) SaaS Apps?

Tags: php, laravel, architecture, crm, erp

I want to build a multitenant SaaS application in PHP with Laravel 5.4. I have prepared for almost every module that is required for architecture but now I am struck with **Automated Custom Fields Generation**.

Like we customize forms in SAP, Oracle eBiz Suit, Sage CRM, Salesforce etc. I want to create a schema like this. So if any user/company requires a custom field or field-set, I don't have to re-write the code. The fields should be added like drag-and-drop feature.

I don't know if this technology has a specific term... But I require some guidance and tutorials on architecture of this module.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by modifying the database.

Let's assume your original database structure is like this.
[image]

Then, you modify the database by adding two tables, one for creating the structure of the custom field, the other for adding the value of the corresponding transaction data.[image]

After that, the image below can be achieved by take into account the relationship between the field of the table. I put the same color for the fields that related to each other.[image]

The rest, I assume you already know how to do it in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have Laravel drag-and-drop, custom form generator similar to a CRM, wufoo, surveymonkey, google forms, formstack, etc... then I recommend:

1. Create your Laravel application and add the authentication: [php artisan make:auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication)
2. Integrate the Form Builder component using a javascript library such as [jQuery Form Builder](https://formbuilder.online/)
3. Create a table for forms that has a foriegn key for user. Store the form layout in JSON as a field in your table.
4. Create a table for submissions that has a foreign key to the form. Store the form submissions in JSON as a field in your table.
5. View the laravel package example on Github [Laravel Drag and Drop Form Builder](https://github.com/jazmy/laravel-formbuilder)